# What registry key is this code creating?

Tags: vbscript, registry, registrykey

I have created registry key by following way:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\application_upgrade"

objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath
```

I have another application. In that application, I have to give Registry key to cross verify. I don't know what is registry key in above code.

I have tried by both name "SOFTWARE\application_upgrade" and "application_upgrade" but I don't get success.

Can anybody tell me what is Registry key in above script? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at this ==> http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_registry_wshshell.php

Comment: It's full registry path should be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\application_upgrade`

Comment: @Hackoo That's just showing another method of writing to the registry, the WMI method is fine I'm not sure how proposing another method when the first one already works helps the OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but you can use something like `regedit.exe` in Windows to view and verify the creation of the key.

You need to include the ROOT *(defined by the named constant `HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001`, in this case is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive in the registry)* when accessing the path so

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\application_upgrade
```

is the fully qualified path the *"other application"* will need to use.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked this all. "Can anybody tell me what is Registry key in above script? or Am I missing something?" I am sure whether above script is right.

Comment: @NanjiMange I can't tell from the comment, if that answered your question?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add value in key? I have tried by adding extra variable: "strValue = "version_10.1.0";" and add this variable at the last
 "objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValue;"  But this doesn't create value in regedit.exe

Comment: @NanjiMange Depends on the type of value you want to set - [MSDN - WMI Tasks: Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394600(v=vs.85).aspx). Remember creating a Key does just that create the Key that can contain values, you then have to assign values *(different for different value types)*. List of members associated with [StdRegProv class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa393664(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @NanjiMange If you wanted a basic string value for example you would use [`SetStringValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa393600(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

This works. It exactly the same as your code with pointless indirection removed.

```
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\application_upgrade"
objRegistry.CreateKey &H80000001,  "SOFTWARE\application_upgrade"
```

Comment: What is pointless about included named constants for ambiguous values like `&H8000001`?

Comment: If you read the question the OP never said the code didn't work, they just wanted to know the full path it creates in the registry. Quote - *"Can anybody tell me what is Registry key in above script?"*